# Nutch read custom fields from DB

Tags: mongodb, field, nutch

I'm trying to add custom field to ES index using Nutch + MongoDB + ES (I've added the custom field values to the DB after the Nutch updateDB step in order to be able to read thm during the index step). 
I've updated webpage.avsc, generate WebPage source (ant generate-gora-src) and updated gora-mongodb-mapping.xml for the new field. By doing that, I thought that I'll see the new field in the WebPage instances, NutchDocument and also in the index but unfortunately what happens is :
- new field is present in WebPage but has null value (I've checked in the DB, it has not null values)
- new field is not present on NutchDocument (I know that I can add it by writing new plugin)
- new field is not present in the index
Do you have an idea why new field is not read from the database to WebPage ? did I miss some thing ?

Many thanks